# Slug route in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

I have this route and it's OK:

```
Router::connect('/tour/:slug', 
     ['controller' => 'Tours','action' => 'view'],
     ['slug'=>'[^\/]+','pass'=>['slug']]
);
```

I want remove "/tour" , but it has Missing Controller error:

```
Router::connect('/:slug', 
     ['controller' => 'Tours','action' => 'view'],
     ['slug'=>'[^\/]+','pass'=>['slug']]
);
```

error page (in request: http://localhost/nextholiday/a_slug ):
 [image]

what should I do?

Comment: Hi, What error do u got ?

Comment: Router::connect('/xxx/:slug', 
     ['controller' => 'Tours','action' => 'view'],
     ['slug'=>'[^\/]+','pass'=>['slug']]
)
Try this URl ot's run ?

Comment: The order you define routes is important, as is the exact error message - and neither are in the question.

Comment: I need  exactly Wordpress URL structure, for example: https://wordpress.org/about/ page

Comment: I've added it before all routes, but didn't work:                                               Router::connect('/:controller',['action' => 'index']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the same route. But it only works when the route is before:

```php
$routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
```

Example (inside of Router::scope('/'...):

```
    $routes->connect(
        '/:slug',
        ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'view'],
        [
            'pass' => ['slug'],
            'slug' => '[^\/]+' // Taken from your example
        ]
    );
    // ...
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
```

If you are doing all right, on DebugKit Routes you will see the routes (URI template) /:controller and /:controller/:action/* just below your /:slug. All other routes must be above of /:slug.

As mentioned, order matters. Missing Controller sometimes is shown if your Regex Pattern is wrong, on slug pattern I'm using "[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this pattern ([^/]+) is bad for me, but it's okay:

```
    $routes->connect( '/:customPageSlug',
    [ 'controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display' ],
    [
        '_name' => 'custom-page'
    ] )->setPatterns( [ 'customPageSlug' => '([\w\/.])*' ] )
       ->setPass( [ 'customPageSlug' ] );
```